# It say UnboundLocalError, How can i update variable after assigning it in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors

```
name = "Aayan"

def AI():
    print("Hi, {}. I hope you are doing well :)".format(name))
    ask = input("How can i help you, {} ? : ".format(name))
    if ask == "change name" or "rename":
        new_name = input("What should I call you ? : ")
        name = new_name
    else:
        exit()

AI()
```

---

It throws UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment.
How can I update name after asking it from the user ?

---

Comment: You should return the value from the function with `return name` and call the function with `name = AI()` so you rebind `name` in the outer scope. Don't use `global`. Never use exit. To cite the documentation of [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit) (and `quit`): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name = "Aayan"

def AI():
    global name
    print("Hi, {}. I hope you are doing well :)".format(name))
    ask = input("How can i help you, {} ? : ".format(name))
    if ask == "change name" or "rename":
        new_name = input("What should I call you ? : ")
        name = new_name
        return name
    else:
        exit()


print(AI())
```

use global keyword inside function and call name

Comment: Now it throws SyntaxError: name 'name' is used prior to global declaration.

Comment: @AaYanYasin Now check the code. Tell me if it not work